# Postgresql: assign default timezone during table creation

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, timezone

I have the following definition of `employees` table

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name text,
  withouttz timestamp without time zone,
  withtz timestamp with time zone,
  CONSTRAINT primarykey_emp PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE employees
  OWNER TO chris;
```

I have inserted two records in the following way:

```
INSERT INTO employees(
            id, name, withouttz, withtz)
    VALUES (1, 'test', '2011-01-01 00:00:00', '2011-01-01 12:00:00+03');

INSERT INTO employees(
            id, name, withouttz, withtz)
    VALUES (2, 'test', '2011-01-01 00:00:00', '2011-01-01 12:00:00');
```

I have written simple java class for `select * from employees` which outputs the following:

```
col1: 1
col2: test
col3: 2011-01-01 00:00:00
col4: 2011-01-01 07:00:00-8:00

col1: 2
col2: test
col3: 2011-01-01 00:00:00
col4: 2011-01-01 12:00:00-8:00
```

Question:
Is there a way to create a postgres table's `timestamp with time zone` so that it considers the timezone to be UTC instead of server's local timezone ?

Note: `set timezone TO 'GMT';` is not a solution for me because it is works in only a specific session. Also, it would be great if the solution doesnot depend on Server's local timezone at all

Thanks in advance

Comment: @null.pointer as I said in my question very clearly, `SET TIMEZONE TO 'GMT';` is not a solution for me.

Comment: Read the documentation on Timezones in the postgresql documentation again. Timezones are based on the clients, not the server. SET TIMEZONE is most definitely a solution.

Comment: Also, you can check out the PGTZ environment variable to automate it.

Comment: Why not pass `+00` as the TZ offset instead of `+03` in your 1st insert or empty in the 2nd insert? That's how UTC is expressed in a `timestamptz` literal. In your example, it's not clear which exact part of the results you didn't expect or what you'd like instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates, times and timestamps are pretty clumsy in SQL.

I suspect that in this case what you want to write will be:

```
TIMESTAMP 'blah blha blah' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

This will define a localtime timestamp (not subject to conversion) then explicitly treat it as a timestamptz in UTC time.

Answer (score 1):

Time zone is a session parameter. It's relatively straight forward to set the session's TIMEZONE.  Also see: [postgres default timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663765/postgres-default-timezone)

`SET TIMEZONE TO 'GMT';` will do the trick.

**EDIT:** I guess you could try `AT TIMEZONE 'GMT';`, but I'm not to sure on the difference between the two.

**EDIT 2:** As Craig Ringer said, the following seems to be what you're looking for.

> `ALTER DATABASE ...` set it's database level. If you change it in
>   `postgresql.conf` it's global. See the manual for details.

Comment: @Chris - "SET TIMEZONE" is a solution for you, because it doesn't only work for a single session. You can apply it cluster-wide, to a specific database or a specific user. See the fine manuals for details. Oh - and this is nothing to do with the server's local timezone, but the clients. Take some time out to read the manual on date/time handling too. It's complicated, but then it has to be.

Comment: @RichardHuxton Thank you for the response. I have just tested it again on Postgresql 9.1 + Ubuntu 13.04. I can confirm again that it holds at session level only. Besides, I would like to have a solution during table creation

Comment: @Chris You're not really going to be able to handle this on the DB side unless you want to code your own logic into it.

Comment: @null.pointer of course you can handle this in the db. chris - either you didn't apply the setting to the database or you are overriding it in the client. You also don't understand what a timestamptz really is. Please take the time to read the date/time and configuration settings of the manual - they explain it quite clearly.

Comment: @Chris If you use `SET` it's session-level. If you use `SET LOCAL` it's transaction level. If you use `ALTER USER ... SET` it's user level. If you use `ALTER DATABASE ... set` it's database level. If you change it in `postgresql.conf` it's global. See the manual for details.

Comment: @CraigRinger I think that's the correct answer.