# timezone aware date_trunc function

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timezone-offset

The following query

```
SELECT the_date FROM date_trunc('day', timestamp with time zone 
       '2001-01-1 00:00:00+0100') as the_date
```

results to

```
the_date
2000-12-31 00:00
```

Is there a way to tell date_trunc to do day/month/year conversions based on the timezone it is feeded with?

The expected output would be: `2001-01-1 00:00+0100`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding `timestamp with time zone`. (That's common, it's a stupid name for the type's actual semantics). `timestamp with time zone` is not in fact a timestamp with a time zone. It's a timestamp stored in UTC that's converted to/from the `TimeZone` of the client on I/O.

Comment: There is a bug in your question. What you call a "date" (`the_date`) actually has the form of a `timestamp` and really should be a `timestamptz`, since the query displayed would return that. We do not know how that result was cooked. Also, the meaning of the timestamp is ambiguous without knowing your local time zone.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I agree that "the_date" is misleading in this context. But what has my local timezone to do with the question?

Comment: The *meaning* of a `timestamp` value depends on your current time zone setting in your client. This may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to specify at which time zone you want it to show

```
select
    date_trunc(
        'day',
        timestamp with time zone '2001-01-1 00:00:00+0100' at time zone '-02'
    ) as the_date;
      the_date       
---------------------
 2001-01-01 00:00:00
```

[`AT TIME ZONE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT)

Comment: This fixes the lower end. But what is with "2001-12-31 24:00:00+0100" > 2002-01-01 00:00:00?

Comment: @Jay midnight is a special case: *can* be referenced from the previous day, but always belongs to the following day. i.e: `select timestamptz '2001-12-31 24:00:00+00'` will yield `2002-01-01 00:00:00+00`

Comment: Note that for this answer to make sense, your Postgres database timezone needs to be set correctly. See its current value with `SHOW timezone;` and change its value with e.g: `ALTER DATABASE <db_name> SET timezone TO 'UTC';`. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663765/postgres-default-timezone

Answer (score 28):

While the marked answer might be correct for the OP's weird circumstances it is more likely incorrect for others. You need to convert the timestamp returned by date_trunc to the proper timezone.

```
select
    date_trunc(
        'day',
        some_timestamp at time zone users_timezone
    ) at time zone users_timezone as the_date;
```

The important thing to understand is `date_trunc` returns a `timestamp` with no timezone attached to it. You need to convert the timestamp to the proper timezone because the database client or whatever downstream might have a different timezone.

Comment: ```at time zone users_timezone as the_date;``` is what saved me.  Thanks man!

Answer (score 4):

@Adam's answer is definitely more helpful. Although I think we can improve on it again because if we're truncating a Timestamp to a single day (or week/month/etc), then we want to make sure that we're dealing with a Date object, not a Timestamp. Otherwise we may give other pieces of code the impression that something just actually *happened* to occur at midnight (or potentially some other misleading time of day).

So I would use:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('day', some_timestamp AT TIME ZONE users_timezone)::date AS the_date;
```

which casts the result to a Date, rather than Timestamp.

The result will be something like:

```sql
  the_date
------------
 2019-09-14
```

instead of the more misleading result of:

```sql
      the_date
---------------------
 2019-09-14 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

For dealing with a Date object, not a Timestamp, @stwr667's answer not working for me.

So I use:

```
SELECT the_date FROM DATE(date_trunc('day', timestamp with time zone 
       '2001-01-1 00:00:00+0100')) as the_date
```

The result:

```
the_date  
----------
2001-01-01
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the third argument:

```sql
SELECT the_date
FROM date_trunc('day', timestamp_with_time_zone, users_timezone) as the_date
```