# Why is at time zone works not as was expected?

Tags: postgresql, date, time, timezone, truncate

I have a server that gives me some information grouped by day, so I tried to use `date_trunc()`, but because of the timezone I know that `2020-06-05 21:00:00` in my DB is actually `2020-06-06 00:00:00`.

So if I just use `date_trunc`, I got `2020-06-05 00:00:00`, but I need `2020-06-06 00:00:00`.

I'm trying this:

```
  select tm ,  date_trunc('day', (tm) at time zone '+3')
   from scm.tbl
  where (tm BETWEEN '2020-06-05 15:00:00+00:00:00' AND '2020-06-08 20:59:00+00:00:00')
  order by tm
```

And I have this:

```
2020-06-05 17:59:59  | 2020-06-05 00:00:00
2020-06-05 18:00:10  | 2020-06-06 00:00:00
```

At 18:00 the date became 2020-06-06, but it shouldn't. Why does it? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the data type of the column `tm`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `AT TIME ZONE` will convert a `timestamp without time zone` into a `timestamp with time zone`, and that is again handled according to your current `timezone` setting.

So you need to use `AT TIME ZONE` twice, first to interpret the timestamp in the correct time zone, and then to extract what an UTC clock would show at that time:

```
SELECT tm, date_trunc('day', tm AT TIME ZONE '+3' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
FROM scm.tbl
WHERE (tm BETWEEN '2020-06-05 15:00:00+00:00:00' AND '2020-06-08 20:59:00+00:00:00')
ORDER BY tm;
```

Comment: It's working, thank you! But I also need to group by day, so I'm doing this: date_trunc('day', min(tm) at time zone '3' at time zone 'UTC') and it's not working as expected - WHERE (tm BETWEEN '2020-06-06 21:00:00+00:00:00' AND '2020-06-08 20:59:00+00:00:00')  must return 3 rows for 07 and 3 rows for 08, but it returns 6 rows for 07 and 3 for 08 like it includes rows for 06... Can you help to solve this?

Comment: Sounds like a new question, but you probably need similar conversions in the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Thank you)) Nothing I'm trying is working for me(except of subquery, but I'd like to do it without them) so I created new question

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here [timezone aware date_trunc function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040039/timezone-aware-date-trunc-functio)

When I saw this in the answer:

```
    timestamp with time zone '2001-01-1 00:00:00+0100' at time zone '-02'
```

It's because tm is +03:00:00 and I'm adding it again...

So what I can do is:

```
   date_trunc('day', tm at time zone '0')
```

I guess there's must be better way to do it, without '0'