# Why my psql set timezone not work?

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I use `set timezone='UTC'`

[image]

And I check the database ,but it's still with time +8  :

[image]

So I reopen the terminal,it still show my timezone is ROC
Why is set timezone not work,Please guide me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It *does* work, exactly as advertised.

Refer to the [documentation for SET](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-set.html):

> SET *only* affects the value used by the current session..
>
> [..SESSION] Specifies that the command takes effect for the current session. (This is the default if neither SESSION nor LOCAL appears.)

Each `psql` client connection establishes a new session that is terminated when the client disconnets.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11443155/2864740) for how to *actually* set a "server default", which may or may not be what the real goal is.