# Why postgres uses different timezone for formatting?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, timezone

I'm running following query from my JS code using `pg`:

```
SELECT begin_at, to_char(begin_at, 'DD.MM') AS dt
FROM tasks
WHERE begin_at >= $1
ORDER BY begin_at
```

Column `begin_at` has type `timestamptz`.

On my PC I get dates in my timezone (UTC+4)
`{ begin_at: "2021-11-02T19:00:00.000Z", dt: "03.11" }` and on server I get `{ begin_at: "2021-11-02T19:00:00.000Z", dt: "02.11" }` for the same database.

Both running `node v16.8.0`, `postgres 13`, both have same time and set postgres timezone to `Asia/Yekaterinburg`

Comment: can you try this `SET TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Yekaterinburg';
SELECT to_char('2021-11-02T19:00:00.000Z'::timestamp with time zone, 'DD.MM') AS dt`?

Comment: Try `to_char(begin_at AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Yekaterinburg', 'DD.MM') AS dt`. Also I'd be curious what the result of `to_char(begin_at, 'TZ') AS tz` is in your two systems.

Comment: Wait, forget about `AT TIME ZONE`. Apparently [the only way to influence rendering timezone in `to_char` is to `set local timezone to '…'`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10797720/1048572). I really would suggest to just query the timestamp from postgres, and do the date formatting in the last possible moment; in your case using a timezone-aware date library (e.g. Temporal or Luxon) in node.js.

Comment: @Bergi yes, it was session timezone. Saving dates as timestamp does not suffer from the same problem?

Comment: You mean saving dates in a column of type `timestamp` (without timezone)? That actually suffers from worse problems, as now the values change (and not just the formatting) when you have a different session timezone.

Comment: @Bergi no, I mean using `int4`

Comment: `int4` is not a timestamp, it's an integer (and a rather small one). Use `timestamptz` for timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

The column `begin_at` is most likely declared without the time zone or the session has a different time zone. See the difference yourself:

```
SET TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Yekaterinburg';
SELECT to_char('2021-11-02T19:00:00.000Z'::timestamp with time zone, 'DD.MM');

 to_char 
---------
 03.11
```

without time zone:

```
SET TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Yekaterinburg';
SELECT to_char('2021-11-02T19:00:00.000Z'::timestamp, 'DD.MM');

 to_char 
---------
 02.11
```

To be sure of the session's `timezone` you might wanna try [`SHOW TIMEZONE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28218103/2275388):

```
SHOW TIMEZONE;

 TimeZone 
----------
 Etc/UTC
```

Check this demo to see the effect of `SET TIMEZONE` in the seesion: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fc952b0bf6451a184bb0eb40e8f877c0)

Comment: OP wrote "*Column `begin_at` has type `timestamptz`*".

Comment: @Bergi fair enough, in this case I would guess the issue is in the sessions' timezone, but it is hard to be sure. Thanks for pointing out. Cheers

Comment: Yeah, from all I read about `to_char` the issue must be the session timezone