# Clojure: java.jdbc can't connect to Postgres after changing OS timezone to UTC

Tags: postgresql, clojure, clojure-java-interop

When I set my timezone on my server to UTC via `timedatectl set-timezone UTC` and restart Postgres server, I can connect via psql and verify that `select now()` returns the correct value.

When I try to start my Clojure app and run a query, I get the following error:

> Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. 
>   While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed 
>   to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed
>   acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "UTC"

I am using the following database libraries in my app:

```
[org.postgresql/postgresql "9.4.1208"]
[clojure.jdbc/clojure.jdbc-c3p0 "0.3.2"]
[org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.6.1"]
```

The error looks like it comes from Postgres, but only happens when connecting via the Clojure app.

Everything works if I return the OS timezone to `America/New_York`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at

[postgres default timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663765/postgres-default-timezone)

See what timezone names are understood by the database:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names;
```

Comment: This helped me to nail it down -- in my Postgres install, it understands "GMT" and "UCT" but not "UTC"