# Error in saving timezone in Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, timezone, asyncpg

Trying to save a date in PostgreSQL using Python, it gives me an UTC+2 for my timezone while it is UTC+1 (dont mind the difference, I just used a Python test to get how the timezone is)

```
In [8]: datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Africa/Algiers"))
Out[8]: datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 7, 15, 27, 43, 756977, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Africa/Algiers' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
```

On PostgreSQL, I get

```
2018-07-07 14:28:04.144505+02
```

[image: timezone different]

This is like postgresql adds a daylight saving while we dont have it in Algeria ?

NB: I use [asyncpg](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/)

Comment: Could be postgresql defualt timezone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663765/postgres-default-timezone

Comment: That's wierd postgresql is wrong by 21 seconds

Comment: @RaymondNijland Checking it, Thank you,
Jasen that's just a test made after few seconds of adding the date to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Raymond Nijland's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224178/error-in-saving-timezone-in-postgresql?noredirect=1#comment89430229_51224178), that worked, here is how (from PGAdmin 4)
The reason is that the OS forces its own timezone and dont save the one that Python gave him.

Just run those three commands from SQL prompt :

To get which timezone PG uses,

```
SHOW timezone ;
```

To get all the timezones available and how PG names them

```
SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names ;
```

Put the right timezone

```
ALTER DATABASE yourDataBase SET timezone TO 'Africa/Algiers';
```

Restart the service

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql-10.service
```

NB: Even if you use `moment.js` you need to add `.zone(+0100)` as mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16703551/861487)