# How to change AWS RDS Postgres database timezone?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, dbeaver

I am trying to change the RDS timezone to UTC,
I'm using an SQL Client called **DBeaver**

**I tried the following two commands -**

**1. Configuration Parameter Name -**

```
SET timezone TO 'UTC';
```

and

**2. Standard SQL Command -**

```
SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

But the `select now();` command still doesn't return the UTC time

**I am referring this answer -**
[postgres default timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663765/postgres-default-timezone)

**Tried the following -**
[image]

```
echo $PGTZ
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

```
ALTER DATABASE your_db_name SET timezone TO 'UTC';
```

Comment: Are you proposing both of those options or just one?

Comment: both sql commands are doing the same thing and both of them change the timezone for the session only, not a permanent change

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are using a connection pool, and session settings get cleared when the session returns to the pool.

You could try something like

```
ALTER ROLE your_user SET timezone = 'UTC';
```

You must reconnect for this to take effect.

Also, check if the environment variable `PGTZ` is set in your environment. It will override the database settings.

If all that doesn't do the trick, consider the possibility that the server's time is off.

Comment: Perhaps the server's clock is wrong? I added that option to the answer.