# Time zone in postgeSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use postgeSQL 12.3. The default timezone is 'US/Pacific'. When i use the `Now()` function, postgres returns the current time and date correctly but with the a time zone different from mine. I changed the time zone to be 'Africa/Cairo' via the command

```
SET TIMEZONE = 'Africa/Cairo';
```

After that, I called the function `Now()` again. It returned a wrong date and time but with a correct time zone. How can i fix this error?. I want the new time (the time after changing the time zone) to be the same as the old time (the time before changing the time zone). In other words, I want to change the time zone only from -7 to +02. What should I do?

Here is the output before changing the time zone

[image]

This is the output after changing the time zone to 'Africa/Cairo'

[image]

Comment: Show both results for both timezones.

Comment: To verify what is happening, perhaps you can provide a screenshot of your terminal session along with a display of current time such a Time.is in a web browser.

Comment: Done. Please check.

Comment: Just a note. Unlike Oracle, PostgreSQL does not store the time zone or time offset information; internally it just stores the timestamp in UTC and converts it back to the server time offset (never to the time zone) when read **on the fly**.

Comment: I know it @TheImpaler

Comment: It will not be 2300 in 'US/Pacific' for another eight-and-a-half hours.  It looks like the server hosting your DB server has its timezone set to 'US/Pacific' and then was forced to show 'Africa/Cairo' time.

Answer (score 1):

I am in  'US/Pacific' so:

```
select now();
              now               
--------------------------------
 07/09/2020 17:23:19.817048 PDT

test(5432)=> SET TIMEZONE = 'Africa/Cairo';
SET

test(5432)=> select now();
              now               
--------------------------------
 07/10/2020 02:24:02.617442 EET
(1 row)

test(5432)=> select now() at time zone  'US/Pacific';
          timezone          
----------------------------
 07/09/2020 17:24:21.577493
(1 row)
```

UPDATE. Example of timestamp, timestamptz:

```
ts_test 
                        Table "public.ts_test"
 Column |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 ts_tz  | timestamp with time zone    |           |          | 
 ts     | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 ts_txt | character varying           |           |          | 

show timezone;
  TimeZone  
------------
 US/Pacific

test(5432)=# insert into ts_test values(localtimestamp, localtimestamp, localtimestamp);
INSERT 0 1
test(5432)=# select * from ts_test ;
             ts_tz              |             ts             |           ts_txt           
--------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
 07/09/2020 17:57:26.005347 PDT | 07/09/2020 17:57:26.005347 | 07/09/2020 17:57:26.005347

test(5432)=# SET TIMEZONE = 'Africa/Cairo';
SET
test(5432)=# insert into ts_test values(localtimestamp, localtimestamp, localtimestamp);
INSERT 0 1
test(5432)=# select * from ts_test ;
             ts_tz              |             ts             |           ts_txt           
--------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
 07/10/2020 02:57:26.005347 EET | 07/09/2020 17:57:26.005347 | 07/09/2020 17:57:26.005347
 07/10/2020 02:57:44.661465 EET | 07/10/2020 02:57:44.661465 | 07/10/2020 02:57:44.661465
(2 rows)

test(5432)=# insert into ts_test values('07/09/2020 5:45', '07/09/2020 5:45', '07/09/2020 5:45');
INSERT 0 1
test(5432)=# select * from ts_test ;
             ts_tz              |             ts             |           ts_txt           
--------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
 07/10/2020 02:57:26.005347 EET | 07/09/2020 17:57:26.005347 | 07/09/2020 17:57:26.005347
 07/10/2020 02:57:44.661465 EET | 07/10/2020 02:57:44.661465 | 07/10/2020 02:57:44.661465
 07/09/2020 05:45:00 EET        | 07/09/2020 05:45:00        | 07/09/2020 5:45

test(5432)=# SET TIMEZONE = default;
SET
test(5432)=# show timezone;
  TimeZone  
------------
 US/Pacific
(1 row)

test(5432)=# insert into ts_test values('07/09/2020 5:45', '07/09/2020 5:45', '07/09/2020 5:45');
INSERT 0 1
test(5432)=# select * from ts_test ;
             ts_tz              |             ts             |           ts_txt           
--------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
 07/09/2020 17:57:26.005347 PDT | 07/09/2020 17:57:26.005347 | 07/09/2020 17:57:26.005347
 07/09/2020 17:57:44.661465 PDT | 07/10/2020 02:57:44.661465 | 07/10/2020 02:57:44.661465
 07/08/2020 20:45:00 PDT        | 07/09/2020 05:45:00        | 07/09/2020 5:45
 07/09/2020 05:45:00 PDT        | 07/09/2020 05:45:00        | 07/09/2020 5:45
(4 rows)
```

Comment: I don`t understand what the benefit of this. The problem is that the time zone is different when switching from US/Pacific to Africa/Cairo. I want time and date to remain as they were before changing the time zone, and just change the time zone from -7 to +02. 
By the way, I use the default server created by the pgAdmin.

Comment: That can't happen, a fixed_timestamp -7 cannot be the same as fixed_timestamp +02 and you really don't want to work without timezones.

Comment: See update to answer to show effect of timestamp vs timestamptz.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into details about the workings of time zones in PostgreSQL (the other answers provided that), here is a solution. You take the local time without time zone and use `AT TIME ZONE` to interpret it in a different time zone:

```
SELECT localtime AT TIME ZONE 'Africa/Cairo';
```

The result will of course be displayed according to the current setting of `timezone`.

Answer (score 0):

## Use `clock_timestamp()` for current moment

`now()` is a traditional PostgreSQL equivalent to `transaction_timestamp()` which in turn is equivalent to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. These three commands return the moment when the transaction began. See [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT).

To get the start time of the current statement, more specifically, the time of receipt of the latest command message from the client, call `statement_timestamp()`.

To capture the moment when the function executes, call `clock_timestamp()`.

## Setting default time zone

You can set the default time zone in either of two ways, as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6663848/642706):

- SQL-standard: `SET TIME ZONE 'Africa/Cairo' ;`
- Postgres-specific: SET timezone TO 'Africa/Cairo' ;

## Example

Here is a screenshot showing three things:

- Current moment as seen in UTC, in the web site Time.is.
- A query showing current default time zone, and the current moment.
- A query (a moment later, as I switched windows) showing a change to the current default time zone, along with a query for current zone and the current moment.

For this demo I used the managed database service by DigitalOcean.com for Postgres 12.

[image: screenshot of Time.is web site showing current moment in UTC, a SQL query showing current default time zone and current moment, and another SQL query changing default time zone, then showing current default time zone and current moment]

We can see in this shot that the current moment in UTC is 2:30 AM. The west coast time in US is 7:30 PM the prior day, seven hours behind UTC. The current default time zone in the first session is UTC (GMT), showing a correct time of 2:30 AM, in agreement with Time.is web site. The second session we switch to `Africa/Cairo` time zone, to find the current moment seen through that time zone is 4:30 AM, two hours ahead of UTC.

All this makes sense, and seems correct to me.

Based on other's comments, I suspect the system clock of your host computer is incorrect. I wonder if the time zone on the server is set to one time zone, but the actually time-of-day is set to the current time of a different time zone. This would only happen if manually set by a sysadmin, I expect, as the host OS should auto-correct if set to check a time server.

To verify this, I suggest you do something similar to what I did, to verify the database server’s clock:

1. Open a browser window for Time.is, selecting UTC.
2. Set current default time zone to UTC: `SET TIME ZONE 'GMT' ;`.
3. Query database for current default time zone and the current moment. Use `clock_timestamp` rather than a transaction-start function like `now` to avoid confusion with a long-running txn.

➥If Time.is does not agree with your result from `clock_timestamp`, then we know your server time is set incorrectly.

Take a screenshot, post with your Question.

Tips:

- Learn to think, work, log, and debug in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Forget about your own parochial time zone while on the job. Think of UTC as the One True Time, and all other zones are but mere variations.
- Generally best to set your servers to UTC (offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).
- I recommend configuring your servers to check with a time server for auto-correction of their clocks, if you have access to reliable time servers.