# Postgres cast to TIMESTAMPTZ

Tags: postgresql

What is the behavior of PostgreSQL when we cast a `DATE` to `TIMESTAMP` to `TIMESTAMPTZ`
What time zone is used?

1. PostgreSQL server
2. Client that run the query (Current session)

Comment: Really. You can't do `select current_date::timestamp, current_date::timestamptz` and see? For more information see [Timestamps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT)(8.5.1.3. Time Stamps)

Comment: What do you mean? Your query works without error and casted successfully

Comment: You wanted to know what the behavior is and that shows you. Look at the output and read the information at the link, it will answer question and more.

Comment: I already read the doc,  and the behavior is not clear, what is the time zone here? Do you know?

Comment: You have not provided enough information. Run `SHOW TimeZone;` Provide an example of the dates being used and the output of the casts. Indicate the client being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting date to timestamp will append time `00:00:00.0` to the date.
The time zone of the current server session will be used.
By default this is the time zone setting of Postgresql server.
You can change the time zone of the current server session like this:

```sql
set time zone 'Europe/Sofia';
```

I do not think that the time zone of the client has any effect. More on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663765/postgres-default-timezone).

- Edit

As Adrian Klaver noticed "When dealing with timestamps it's best to assume the worst". Therefore better set the session time zone explicitly.

Comment: The client's time zone has an effect, especially when comparing `timestamp` and timestamptz` types. It determines what the initial time zone is for the passed in value. In the `timestamp` case it becomes a tz naive value that loses its time zone information. In the `timestamptz` case it gets rotated to `UTC` depending on the `TimeZone` value, which can be changed by the client.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I mean casting only because it seems to me that this is what the question is about. BTW are there clients that implicitly set the time zone of the connection/session?

Comment: I have seen cases where folks had the env variable `PGTZ`[Env](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) set which caused all `libpq` sessions to change the time zone. Also where folks did an explicit `SET timezone ...` in their connection set up. When dealing with timestamps it best to assume the worst.

Answer (score 4):

If you cast a `date` to a `timestamp`, time zones don't play a role, because both data types are without a time zone. The resulting timestamp will be the beginning of the day.

If you cast `date` to `timestamp with time zone`, resulting timestamp will be the beginning of the date in the time zone defined by the parameter `timezone` in your current session.

```
SHOW timezone;

   TimeZone    
---------------
 Europe/Vienna
(1 row)

SELECT CAST (DATE '2021-01-15' AS timestamp);

      timestamp      
---------------------
 2021-01-15 00:00:00
(1 row)

SELECT CAST (DATE '2021-01-15' AS timestamp with time zone);

      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2021-01-15 00:00:00+01
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the situation where one needs to change the column type from `integer` (as epoc seconds) to `timzezonetz` ->
casting directly from `integer` to `timezonetz` is not possible.
but you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE timestamptz 
  USING column_name::abstime::timestamptz
```