# PostgreSQL timezone takes Windows OS timezone automatically

Tags: windows, postgresql, timezone

While installing Postgresql DB 13.0-1 x64 on Windows, if I comment the "timezone" key on postgresql.conf file then "show timezone" sql query gives me "GMT".

How could I do for the timezone to be the same than my Windows OS's timezone automatically, without running the "ALTER timezone" query manually myself ?

Thanks

Comment: For current session you can set timezone manually.
See solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663765/postgres-default-timezone)

Comment: Do you want the time zone from the client machine (which would make sense) or from the server machine (which makes less sense)?

Comment: I want the timezone of the server machine, the one hosting the database. Thanks

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, actually the client and the server machine are the same. In Oracle db the OS timezone is used automatically, there is no need to specify a timezone to the db. I would like the same behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not try to determine the operating system time zone when the server is started, but when the database cluster is created with `initdb`.
During `initdb`, PostreSQL tries to determine the correct IANA time zone from the operating system. See this excerpt from `src/bin/initdb/findtimezone.c`:

```c
/*
 * The following block of code attempts to determine which timezone in our
 * timezone database is the best match for the active system timezone.
 *
 * On most systems, we rely on trying to match the observable behavior of
 * the C library's localtime() function. [...]
 *
 * Win32's native knowledge about timezones appears to be too incomplete
 * and too different from the IANA database for the above matching strategy
 * to be of any use. But there is just a limited number of timezones
 * available, so we can rely on a handmade mapping table instead.
 */

[...]

    /*
     * This list was built from the contents of the registry at
     * HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time
     * Zones on Windows 7, Windows 10, and Windows Server 2019.  Some recent
     * additions have been made by comparing to the CLDR project's
     * windowsZones.xml file.
     *
     * The zones have been matched to IANA timezones based on CLDR's mapping
     * for "territory 001".
     */
    {
        /* (UTC+04:30) Kabul */
        "Afghanistan Standard Time", "Afghanistan Daylight Time",
        "Asia/Kabul"
    },
    {
        /* (UTC-09:00) Alaska */
        "Alaskan Standard Time", "Alaskan Daylight Time",
        "America/Anchorage"
    },
    [...]
    {
        /* (UTC-07:00) Yukon */
        "Yukon Standard Time", "Yukon Daylight Time",
        "America/Whitehorse"
    },
    {
        NULL, NULL, NULL
    }
```

The code then calls `localtime(time(NULL))` and gets the system time zone name using `strftime()` with the format `%Z`. If that matches an entry in the above list, we are done. Otherwise PostgreSQL scans the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` registry entries under `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zone` for a match. If none is found, `GMT` will be used.

That value is stored in `postgresql.conf` and determines the default time zone. If you remove that entry from `postgresql.conf`, PostgreSQL will fall back to the default value `GMT`.

So the solution is *not* to remove the entry from `postgresql.conf`, but to run `initdb` when you need a database cluster on a new machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot Laurenz, unfortunately initdb is made when the server is in France , then it is sent and used in India. I will write a script which sets the current timezone to postgresql.conf, then run it in India

Comment: Sure, that is a good solution.